# Convert a game asset to image

Tags: google-play-games

I have a game on my phone that I really like. I was astonished by the portraits of the characters. I found the portrait within the game files but it has no extension, but I know myself it's counted as an image file within the game. Is there any way to convert the game asset into any image format?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to add common image extensions to that file, such as .jpg, .png, .gif

Comment: Tried, doesn't work.